# how to scan qr code in windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code

I want to scan qr code in windows phone 8.1.I am using below code

```
  xmlns:jwqr="clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"

xaml page:
<jwqr:QRCodeScanner
    ScanComplete="QRCodeScanner_ScanComplete"
    Error="QRCodeScanner_Error"
    Width="400"
    Height="400"/>
```

but it show sbelow error:
The name "QRCodeScanner" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:JeffWilcox.Controls;assembly=JeffWilcox.Controls.QR"

Comment: Try to clean solution -> rebuild solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scan QR code in windows phone app 8.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634194/how-to-scan-qr-code-in-windows-phone-app-8-1)

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to add the assembly reference first [as described here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/wpqr-control/)?